# Appending certain elements from a list of list into another list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested list as shown below:

```
L = [['James', 'Bob', '23', '47'], ['Earl', 'Carl', '16', '43'], ['Milly', 'Wendy', '1', '21']]
```

I want to take the names from each of them and put them into a new list called 'newList' without the numbers.

I tried the following code:

```
for i in L[0][0]:
    newList.append(i)
print(newList)
```

However, this just printed the first name and each letter was seperated by a comma. I want the new list to look like this:

```
newList = ['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over elements in list `L`

```
for i in L:
    newList.append(i[0])
    newList.append(i[1])
    #or simply newList.extend(i[:2])
print(newList)
```

**EDIT**

```
for i in L:
    if i[0] not in newList:
        newList.append(i[0])
    if i[1] not in newList:
        newList.append(i[1])
    #or simply newList.extend(i[:2])
print(newList)
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I alter this so that if I had a nested list with repeated names it would only print the name once in the new list?

Comment: Here `i[0]` is the first element, `i[1]` is the second element.You can check whether equal or not before `append`

Comment: I tried putting `if i[0] != i[1]` after the for statement and before the appending statements. This however just produced the same result as before.

Comment: I dont undertand repeating names, is that in same list or in diferent list?

Comment: In a different list, for example: `[['James', 'Alan'], ['Alan', 'James']]` It would only print `['James', 'Alan']`

Answer (score 3):

Just use a nested list comprehension:

```
In [61]: [i for sub in L for i in sub[:2]]
Out[61]: ['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isdigit()` to filter out names

```
res = [j for i in L for j in i if not j.isdigit()]
['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps.

First, grab the first two elements of each list:

```
>>> names_nested = [sub[:2] for sub in L]
>>> names_nested
[['James', 'Bob'], ['Earl', 'Carl'], ['Milly', 'Wendy']]
```

Then unnest this list:

```
>>> names = [name for sub in names_nested for name in sub]
>>> names
['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

... or do it more comfortably with `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*(sub[:2] for sub in L)))
['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

... or `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to get rid of the unpacking star and one set of parentheses.

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(sub[:2] for sub in L))
['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is simply the first two elements from each sublist you can do:

```
from itertools import chain
result = chain.from_iterable(sublist[:2] for sublist in L)
```

This will produce a chain object, you can use `list` to evaluate it:

```
list(result)
# ['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy to slice the list and flatten the results to a 1D list:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(L)[:,0:2].flatten().tolist()
Out[349]: ['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the isdigit method to see if a str is a digit:

```
[j for l in L for j in l if not j.isdigit()]
```

Output:

```
['James', 'Bob', 'Earl', 'Carl', 'Milly', 'Wendy']
```